# How to write a path that includes two keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, rails-routing

I have two models, Artist and Song. Each Artist has_many Songs. I want to write a path for Songs that includes both the Song and Artist in the url.

My route: `get 'songs/:artist/:id' => 'songs#song', as: 'song'`

For example, the url for "Imagine" by "John Lennon" would be `/songs/John%20Lennon/Imagine`.

That url works fine. What I can't figure out is how to write a path for it. These don't work:

```
song_path(song: "Imagine", artist: "John Lennon")
song_path("John Lennon", "Imagine")
```

Anyone know the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Rails 5? `resource_path` is deprecated in Rails 5. You can still use `link_to "song title", song_path(artist: "John Lennon", id: "Imagine")`

Also, notice that you pass the key "song" in option 1 and you define the route with "id".